# Change Device.StartTimer() interval while running in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a way to change the interval while the timer is running.
I haven't found a solution in the Microsoft docs, nor on Google.

Is that actually possible?

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () =>
{
    ... Change interval here, for example to 8 seconds
}
```

Comment: use System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a new timer                  .

Comment: Anton, your reply is way too short. Can I kindly ask you to add something more. Eg: code sample.

Comment: Would that be possible like this?
`
int refresh = 10;
startTimer(refresh);

void startTimer(int p1) {
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(p1), () =>
    {
        int secs = App._restService.getIntervalFromServer();
        if (secs != refresh) {
            refresh = secs;
            startTimer(secs);
            return false; // to exit the current timer
        }
    }
`

Comment: Anton, thanks, the hint helped. I got it running the way I sketched it in my previous comment.